# Why does superclass B invoke subclass A's method?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, polymorphism

The Test3.java:

```
public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}

class A extends B {

    A() {
        System.out.println("Now in A()");
    }

    void m() {
        System.out.println("Now in m() of A");
    }
}

class B {
    B() {
        System.out.println("Now in B()");
        m();
    }

    void m() {
        System.out.println("Now in m() of B");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
    $ java Test3
Now in B()
Now in m() of A
Now in A()
```

Why not "Now in m() of B" in the 2nd line of output?

Comment: C++ and Java are two different languages and have slightly different rules for polymorphism. I suggest you read a book or tutorial about inheritence and polymorphism. This question has already been answered multiple times.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What does this have to do with C++? Also, if it's been answered before, then mark it as a duplicate...

Comment: @AnubianNoob What it has do with C++ is that in C++ the code would behave as the OP expects.

Comment: Note that in the above code A is the subclass, B is the superclass -- contrary to your title.

Comment: @AnubianNoob The OP originally tagged this as both "java" and "C++". (See the edit history.) In particular, the default binding of a member function/method is different in these two languages.

Comment: Oh ok. But if you're not going to mark it as a duplicate, then don;t say it's been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because methods in Java are `virtual` by default, if you using Java 6 or higher, it is recommended that you use the `@Override` annotation, it makes things clearer.

The first question is: Why the first line was

```
Now in B()
```

The reason is: When you can extend a class in Java a call to the `super constructor` will be done automatically for you by the compiler

```
A() {
    super(); // added by Java !!
    System.out.println("Now in A()");
}
```

So, now we are in `B's constructor`

```
B() {
    System.out.println("Now in B()"); // print this
    m(); // Ohh hang on, m() is overridden
}
```

because `m()` is overriden by the subclass A, and the actual instance is of type A, so we will call A's implementation of m(), and that is a polymorphic call.

Comment: Much better explained than me, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Because the method `m` is overriden in `A`. So when it goes to the super constructor, and calls `m`, the object is still an instance of `A`, so it calls the method in `A`.